# Как перевести текст сообщения в нижний регистр в чат боте телеграмм (библиотека aiogram)?

Tags: python, aiogram

Проблема вот в чем (распишу код), при вводе пользователем сообщения "Союзный" (с маленькой буквы или с большой) или "Союз", у меня начинает искать в БД по столбцу Name1 и должен выдать потом все найденные записи. Но в БД, в столбце Name1, текст может содержать как с большой буквы так и с маленькой, в общем прочие варианты (их много). Ранее использовал "if message.text.lower() == "привет":" и все работало, думал передать сообщение пользователя в переменную (по которому искалось в БД) и применить к нему ".lower()", примерно так "message.text.lower() == Name:". Ничего не получилось. Думал может быть получится сделать это в переменной сразу, к примеру вот так "name = message.text.lower()" или "name = message.text.lower() ==message.text", но все равно не получилось. Как можно сделать, что бы при вводе пользователем сообщения (любого, хоть такого "СоЮз"), применялся нижний регистр. или может быть мне это не поможет и мне нужно в самой БД приводить к единому, т.е. поменять "Союзный" или "СоЮзНыЙ" на "союзный"?

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=ShopCentre_name.shop_centre_name)
async def shop_centre_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    name = message.text
    if name.lower():
        name_1 = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM shopCentre WHERE Name1 LIKE '%{name}%'").fetchall()
        num_col = len(name_1)
        if name == '/Stop':
            await message.answer('Поиск завершен. Для поиска введите команду /start (аналогичные команды - /ы и /s)')
            await state.finish()
        else:
            await message.answer('Количество найденных записей:\n' + '<b>' + str(num_col) + '</b>' + '\n\nДля завершения поиска, нажмите на /Stop.')
            for row in name_1:
                await message.answer('Наименование торгового центра:\n' + '<b>' + row[1] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Кадастровый номер объекта налогообложения:\n'+ '<b>' + row[3] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Вид объекта:\n' + '<b>' + row[2] + '</b>')
```

Дополнительно к моему вопросу:
Попробовал написать код, но нужного результата не дало (см. скрин.1):

```
@dp.message_handler(state=ShopCentre_name.shop_centre_name)
async def shop_centre_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    name = message.text.lower()
    name_1 = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM shopCentre WHERE Name1 LIKE '%{name}%'").fetchall()
    num_col = len(name_1)
    if name == '/Stop':
            await message.answer('Поиск завершен. Для поиска введите команду /start (аналогичные команды - /ы и /s)')
            await state.finish()
    else:
        await message.answer('Количество найденных записей:\n' + '<b>' + str(num_col) + '</b>' + '\n\nДля завершения поиска, нажмите на /Stop.')
        for row in name_1:
            await message.answer('Наименование торгового центра:\n' + '<b>' + row[1] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Кадастровый номер объекта налогообложения:\n'+ '<b>' + row[3] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Вид объекта:\n' + '<b>' + row[2] + '</b>')
```

```
Также, думал написать код вот так "async def shop_centre_name(message: types.Message.text.lower(), state: FSMContext):" или подобные варианты, но выдавало ошибку, т.к. просто не знаю, можно ли сюда прописать ".lower()".
```

Результат выполнения кода (скрин.1)

[image: Результат выполнения кода (скрин.1)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ни один из вариантов не помог найти ответ. Пробовал все, если в одном случае помогало, к примеру найти в бд "АТОЛЛ", то простую запись "ТЦ Китеж" нет и т.д. Пробовал варианты предложенные по следующим ссылкам:

https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.10e2cfcf-626a4395-77380ca7-74722d776562/https/stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-%20string-comparing

https://qna.habr.com/q/186215

https://zametkinapolyah.ru/zametki-o-mysql/chast-11-1-ogranicheniya-urovnya-stolbca-v-bazax-dannyx-sqlite.html

Получилось добиться результата путем редактирования БД под единое написание, маленькими буквами к примеру "атолл" без лишних слов типа "ТЦ".

Answer (score 0):

В целом, логика у Вас правильная, но в реализации небольшая ошибка.

```py
@dp.message_handler(state=ShopCentre_name.shop_centre_name)
async def shop_centre_name(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    name = message.text.lower()
    name_1 = cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM shopCentre WHERE Name1 LIKE '%{name}%'").fetchall()
    num_col = len(name_1)
    if name == '/Stop':
        await message.answer('Поиск завершен. Для поиска введите команду /start (аналогичные команды - /ы и /s)')
        await state.finish()
    else:
        await message.answer('Количество найденных записей:\n' + '<b>' + str(num_col) + '</b>' + '\n\nДля завершения поиска, нажмите на /Stop.')
        for row in name_1:
            await message.answer('Наименование торгового центра:\n' + '<b>' + row[1] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Кадастровый номер объекта налогоообложения:\n'+ '<b>' + row[3] + '</b>' + '\n\n' + 'Вид объекта:\n' + '<b>' + row[2] + '</b>')
```

Comment: Так тоже делал, не помогло... что то находит а что то нет. Видимо нужно БД по этой колонке приводить к единому написанию